RN Flatlist center middle item in the middle of the screen
I have a React-Native component where im trying to create a "image" gallery of different items for the user to select.
After multiple hours of debugging i dont understand why the center item always is abit offset?
I have implemented a solution where the "GradeSelector" is using a flatList and Animations to create a "gallery" where the user can select the current item, my issue is that im not able to correcly center my items, and after a buch of testing with different parameters ive not yet been able to center it correctly.
In the code here im using Animated from react-native
My code:
  const { width } = Dimensions.get("window");
  const ITEM_SIZE = width * 0.3;
  const SPACER_ITEM_SIZE = (width - ITEM_SIZE) / 2;

  const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);



 const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    if (item.key === "left-spacer" || item.key === "right-spacer") {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            width: SPACER_ITEM_SIZE,

            height: 50,
          }}
        ></View>
      );
    }

    const inputRange = [
      (index - 3) * ITEM_SIZE,
      (index - 2) * ITEM_SIZE,
      (index - 1) * ITEM_SIZE,
      index * ITEM_SIZE,
      (index + 1) * ITEM_SIZE,
    ];

    const scale = scrollX.interpolate({
      inputRange,
      outputRange: [0.6, 0.75, 1, 0.75, 0.6],
      extrapolate: "clamp",
    });

    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          {
            width: ITEM_SIZE,

            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
          },
          { transform: [{ scale }] },
        ]}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            width: ITEM_SIZE,
            height: ITEM_SIZE * 0.9,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            borderRadius: 10,
            backgroundColor: item.color,
          }}
          onPress={() => handlePress(index)}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 16 }}>{item.text}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  };



return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Animated.FlatList
        ref={flatListRef}
        data={[{ key: "left-spacer" }, ...data, { key: "right-spacer" }]}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id || item.key}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        contentContainerStyle={{ alignItems: "center" }}
        snapToInterval={ITEM_SIZE}
        snapToAlignment="center"
        decelerationRate="fast"
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
          { useNativeDriver: true }
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );

Current center:

Wanted center:

